# UIView.animate with Duration ist not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation

`UIView.animate` is not working in the "else" part of my code. However, it works perfectly fine in the "if" statement. Any suggestions what could cause this issue?

```
    if notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification ||
        notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification {

        // Keyboard shows
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            let heightHelper = self.bottomConstraint.constant
            self.bottomConstraint.constant = keyboardRect.height + 20

            self.bottomConstraintEmail.constant += keyboardRect.height + 20 - heightHelper
            self.anmeldenLabel.alpha = 0
            self.logoConstraint.constant = 45
        }
    } else {
        // Keyboard hides
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.bottomConstraintEmail.constant = 337
            self.bottomConstraint.constant = 255.5
            self.logoConstraint.constant = 60
            self.anmeldenLabel.alpha = 1
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the else block ever executed?

Comment: yes. And everything works except for the animation

Comment: Try removing the first call to layoutIfNeeded. Set the constraints prior to calling animate and only call layoutIfNeeded within the animate block.

Comment: What do you mean it's not working? Not animating? not executing, not applying even when you rotate the phone and rotate it back to manually trigger the layout function? And do you handle `didShow` notification?

Comment: thanks, the call "layoutIfNeeded" was the problem

Answer (score 1):

**@Don** is totally right: `layoutIfNeeded()` should be called after the new constrains have been set.

This should work properly:

```
if notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification ||
    notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification {

    // Keyboard shows
    let heightHelper = self.bottomConstraint.constant
    self.bottomConstraint.constant = keyboardRect.height + 20

    self.bottomConstraintEmail.constant += keyboardRect.height + 20 - heightHelper
    self.anmeldenLabel.alpha = 0
    self.logoConstraint.constant = 45

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
} else {
    // Keyboard hides
    self.bottomConstraintEmail.constant = 337
    self.bottomConstraint.constant = 255.5
    self.logoConstraint.constant = 60
    self.anmeldenLabel.alpha = 1

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```